# Linear transformations $A$ for which $n^{*}A n$ is constant for all unit vectors $n$.

Tags: linear-transformations

Is there a name for linear transformations $A$ for which $n^{*} A n$ is constant for all unit vectors $n$?

The expression looks like the first fundamental form, if $A$ is symmetric, of course.

These are surprisingly non-obvious, the answer depending strongly on dimension.  In $R^2$, they are just the rotations.  In $R^3$, they are rotations with a scaling in the axial direction by the cosine of the angle of rotation.

Comment: Do you mean $n^*$ is the transpose or conjugate transpose? Where do the coefficients of $A$ come from?

Comment: Is $n^*$ the transpose? In that case you are missing many other examples. For instance, a multiple of any 'rotation' will also result in a constant $n^*An$ for all $n^*n=1$. Conversely, if $c$ is the constant, then $U=\frac{1}{c}A$ is a matrix such that $n^*Un=1$  for all $n^*n=1$. This means that if $n_1,...,n_m$ is an orthonormal basis, then $1=\frac{1}{2}(n_i+n_j)^*U(n_i+n_j)=\frac{1}{2}(1+1+2n_i^*Un_j)$, which implies $n_j^*Un_j=0$, for $i\neq j$. This means that $U$ sends orthonormal bases to orthonormal bases. Therefore, the matrices that you are looking for are multiples of unitaries.

Comment: Yes, a constant multiple of a rotation works in 2D, as does any constant multiple of any solution to the problem.
The 3D example I gave is not unitary -- I suspect you are assuming something I didn't suggest.

Comment: @SteveWhite You should edit the original question and fix the errors of what you are saying has this property. If all you really want is a name of this family of matrices you should provide more explicit examples and maybe some more explicit ideas in your line of thought. It's possible someone may know this family from a different context and just not recognize them based on what you've said.

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure I wrote exactly what I meant.  From the context, I think it's pretty clear the asterisk * means the dual (in the case of finite-dimensional real spaces, the transpose.)

Comment: "... I think there is a richer set of solutions... but I haven't really looked."  This. Just this.

Answer (score 1):

To close this, the last fact required is that any linear transform of a space can be decomposed into the sum of a symmetric transform and a skew-symmetric transform.

Let $A$ be a linear transform of a space into itself. Set $B = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^*)$ and $C = \frac{1}{2} (A - A^*)$.  Thus $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is skew-symmetric, and $A = B + C$.  As we have observed, $x^* C x = 0$ for any $x$.  So

$x^* A x = x^* (B + C) x = x^* B x$

The general solution then is the sum of a symmetric solution of the problem with any skew symmetric matix.  And we know already the solution for the symmetric case.

Answer (score 0):

In $R^3$ another class of solution consists of rotations of multiples of the case I mentioned in the original post:

$$
\begin{matrix}
c &  0 &  0 \\
0 &  c &  s \\
0 & -s &  c \\
\end{matrix}
$$
where $c^2 + s^2 = 1$.

It was this example that first got my attention.

Comment: These correspond to the following in my answer $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0                   & 0 \\
0       & \lambda e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
0       &  0 & \lambda e^{-i\theta}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Hi, N8tron, the matrix you wrote maps $C^3$ to itself -- a subalgebra of $R^6$.  Mine maps $R^3$ to itself.  I don't see the correspondence. 
Generally, operators on complex spaces are special cases of operators on real spaces.  The operator I wrote lives only in a real space, I think.

(Well I suppose you could just lop dimensions off the $R^6$ but that's messy.)

Comment: This happens whenever you have complex eigenvalues of a real matrix. In two dimensions if matrix $A$ has complex eigenvalues $a\pm bi$ with eigenvectors $v=v_1\pm v_2i$ you can conjugate by real matrix $P=[v_1,v_2]$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}$ (looks like yours). If you instead conjugate by the complex matrix $V=[v_1+v_2i,v_1-v_2i]$ you'll get $\begin{bmatrix}a+bi & 0 \\ 0 & a-bi \end{bmatrix}$. It's just a matter of what coefficients you'll allow the matrix you're conjugating by to have. Since I want to use the Jordan form, it's most natural to work over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I think the $c^2+s^2=1$ condition is unnecessary take a look at $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & -1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ it has $x^TAx=0$ for all $x$ (not just unit vectors) and $c^2+s^2=1/4$. The zero matrix also has this property, but it is trivial :)

Comment: Sure... i hadn't been interested in singular caes, but there you have another important class of solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how your complex calculations help in the 3x3 case.  It perplexes me that you wrote a 2x2 real matrix and said it looked like my 3x3 case -- which to me is the first interesting case.  To me the 2x2 is just a rotation, which is the first non-trivial solution that occurred to me -- and from there any orthogonal matrix.
But the 3x3 combined rotation and anisometric scaling is an interesting structure.

Comment: Steve, I wasn't meaning to imply that the $2\times 2$ matrix has the same property as these examples. Just trying to illustrate the connection between a complexly conjugated matrix and real conjugated matrix when there are complex eigenvalues (the simplest case is 2x2). I agree the 3x3 are the first interesting case I've been thinking about the conjugation too. I think there every 3x3 matrix of this type will be conjugate by a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ to one as listed in your answer. I've been looking at using the singular value decomposition to characterize all $n \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar approach to classify some colleagues of mine came up with:

Having $\lambda = v^tAv$ is equivalent to having $v^t(A-\lambda I)v=0$

So it suffices to classify the $A$ for which $v^tAv=0$ these have to be skew symmetric because $0=v^tAv=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}v_iv_j$ thus $a_{ij}+a_{ji}=0$ for all $i,j$. So $A^t=-A$.

Thus for any $\lambda$ we can write $A=X+\lambda I$ where $X$ is skew symmetric $X^t=-X$